# Forwarding Meeting invites to Teams Rooms

Tags: activesync, microsoft-365, microsoft-teams

We're currently looking into simplifying our Teams usage in the organisation. In particular, our static Teams Rooms.

The biggest issue we are facing is how to manage external invites.

First off, we're not using Outlook for email due to specific requirements relating to document management, however the behaviour is visible in a number of non-microsoft email clients. Essentially, if we forward an invite onto a Teams Room address it's only possible to see the invite data if the email containing the invite is forwarded as an attachment (i.e an msg attachment), it won't, however, be accepted as an invite and would require manual handling to add to the calendar (i.e. if it is an attachment, login to the mailbox of the Teams Room, open the email (in Outlook/Outlook Web), then the attachment and hopefully I can then accept/add to calendar). But I can't figure a way to correctly manage this so it can work.

My other option would be to try and sync the EDMS and Teams calendars - At least then our EDMS Calendar entries have a fighting chance - The calendar is accessible as a pseudo ActiveSync calendar, but I've not found a way to add the calendar to a Outlook Web account and we don't want to depend on Desktop apps for managing it if we can help it.

I mean the simple solution would be 365 all the things, but then our EDMS doesn't work as expected and that's critical. So I am trying to work out whether there is something I am missing, or how others have approached it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to configure the Teams Room to accept meeting invites from external senders and then send the meeting invites directly to the Teams Room, rather than forwarding the meeting invite (add the Teams Room email address as an attendee or resource). You can configure the Teams Room to accept meeting invites from external senders using the following command after connecting to Exchange Online with Powershell.

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity teamsroom@yourdomain.com -ProcessExternalMeetingMessages $True
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with joeqwerty.
You can get more details about this issue from the following document.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/calendars/meeting-requests-routed-through-third-party-service-not-auto-processed